# Error when running rake assets:precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I am in an uneviable situation where I have to deploy a ruby one rail application on a ubuntu server without any documentation and without much experience in ruby (or ruby on rails).
I tried to follow the steps listed out in various forums/tutorials. I have started the WEBricks server on port 80, but the minute I try to access the web application from a browser I get the following not he browser.

```
couldn't find file './compiled/admin' under '/home/ubuntu/www/my-app/app/assets/stylesheets' with type 'text/css'
```

Then someone suggested that I run
       `rake assets:precompile`

When I run this command I get the following error...

```
    DEPRECATION WARNING: Currently, Active Record suppresses errors raised within `after_rollback`/`after_commit` callbacks and only print them to the logs. In the next version, these errors will no longer be suppressed. Instead, the errors will propagate normally just like in other Active Record callbacks.

You can opt into the new behavior and remove this warning by setting:

  config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

 (called from <class:User> at /home/ubuntu/www/my-app/app/models/user.rb:27)
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file './compiled/admin' under '/home/ubuntu/www/my-app/app/assets/stylesheets' with type 'text/css'
/home/ubuntu/www/my-app/app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css:10
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:64:in `resolve!'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:130:in `block in find'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:129:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:129:in `find'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any help will be much appreciated. If you want me to provide any other information please ask.

The following is the app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css file

```
/*
 * Admin stylesheets
 *
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require_tree ./plugins
 *= require_tree ./fonts
 *
 * Pull compiled from /app/assets/stylesheets/compiled
 *= require ./compiled/admin
 *
 */
```

The Gemfile looks like this.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.3'
gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'pg'

#bootstrap components
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem "select2-rails"

#images upload
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.6'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'awesome_print' # https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: [:production, :staging]

#user managment
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'recaptcha', require: 'recaptcha/rails'
#tracking user data
gem 'classy_enum'

#pagination
gem 'kaminari'

#api serialization
gem 'active_model_serializers'
# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
gem 'jbuilder'

#dropbox
gem "dropbox-api"

#sidekiq jobs
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-status'
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil

#for the folders hierarchy tree
gem 'closure_tree'

# PDFs
gem 'doc_raptor'

# Excel Parsing
gem 'roo'

# Emails
gem 'sendgrid'

# auto increment numbers
gem 'protokoll'

# State machine
gem 'aasm'

#elastic search
gem 'elasticsearch-model', git: 'git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', git: 'git://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails.git'

gem 'rubyzip'

gem 'exception_notification', group: [:production, :staging], github: 'joshco/exception_notification'

gem 'spreadsheet'
```

list of files in the app folder

```
drwxrwxr-x 11 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 app
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 bin
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 client
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  5 22:08 config
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  153 Apr  1 08:03 config.ru
drwxrwxr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 db
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 1570 Apr  1 08:03 Gemfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 9072 Apr  1 08:03 Gemfile.lock
drwxrwxr-x  5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 gulp
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  557 Apr  1 08:03 gulpfile.js
drwxrwxr-x  6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 lib
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  6 13:48 log
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 1393 Apr  1 08:03 package.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  146 Apr  1 08:03 Procfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  143 Apr  1 08:03 Procfile.example
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 public
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu  249 Apr  1 08:03 Rakefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 7908 Apr  1 08:03 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 test
drwxrwxr-x  6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  5 15:14 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  1 08:03 vendor
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   64 Apr  1 08:03 webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Could you please post the file `app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css`?

Comment: @born4new edited question to add app/assets/stylesheets/admin.css.

Comment: Cool thanks. Could you please post your gemfile as well? I suspect you need to launch a command (bower, grunt, etc) that would create the files inside this `stylesheeets/compiled` folder. Also, you could search the whole project for these patterns: `stylesheets/compiled` or `compiled` and see what it yields.

Comment: what is contents of `app/assets/stylesheets/compiled/` ?

Comment: @born4new added Gemfile.

Comment: @Vadfed, there is no such folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need to generate the files that will go in this `stylesheets/compiled` folder.

Two options:

1. Find out how to generate them (check at the root of the project if you have files regarding bower, grunt, etc. If you do, I'd you need to launch these to actually generate the files) and add corresponding deploy rule before asset compilation or commit the results.
2. Remove this line from your `admin.css` file:

   `*= require ./compiled/admin`